# How can we compute this conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces, conditional-expectation

**The problem:**

Suppose $(X_1,...,X_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $Y \in \mathbb{R}$ are random variable such that $(X_1,...,X_d,Y)$ is a gaussian vector.

How can we prove $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid \sigma(X)]$ is a linear combination of $(X_i)$?

I tried first proving $\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{R}} X_i$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega,\sigma(X))$ or equal but I cannot conclude.

**Edit:**

As remarked in the comments it would be more interesting if we consider $\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{R}} (X_i,1)$.

Comment: It's not true ! Nevertheless, there is a Borel function $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ s.t. $\mathbb E[Y\mid \sigma (X)]=f(X_1,...,X_d)$.

Comment: @Surb I imagine showing a counterexample can be difficult, but how can I approach this situation?

Comment: Finding a counter example is not hard : take $X$ and $Y$ independent with $\mathbb E[Y]\neq 0$. Then $\mathbb E[Y\mid \sigma (X)]=\mathbb E[Y]\notin Span(X).$

Comment: @Surb And if we esclude this case?

Comment: would $(X,Y)$ be gaussian then?

Comment: @Surb But the ipothesis is that $(X_1,...,X_d,Y)=(X,Y)$ is gaussian

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini: Thanks you for telling me that, I didn't pay attention to this condition at all... so my previous example counter-example doesn't work. Anyway, the first one works :-)

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini you intented to ask about $Span(X_i)$ or Affine combination of $X_i$ (that is you allow $+ constant$) ? The second would be more interesting.

Comment: @DominikKutek I agree with you, "affine combination" would be more interesting! I will modify the question.

Comment: @Surb Yes, your first suggestion works. But if we change the problem as above? Do you have any idea?

Comment: $$
\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]=\mathsf{E}Y+\frac{\mathsf{E}(Y-\mathsf{E}Y)X^{\top}}{\operatorname{Var}(Y)}(X-\mathsf{E}X).
$$

Comment: @d.k.o. How did you get it? Could you please write it down for me?

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Just compute the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$ as LostStatistician18 suggested.

Comment: @d.k.o. But if we do not have density?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint density of the variables with $Y$ included. This is a Gaussian density function by assumption. The conditional mean is almost surely equal to the mean of the conditional density

$$
f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy}.
$$
Namely, you can show that
$$
E(Y|X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} yf_{Y|X}(y|X)dy  \;\; a.s.
$$

The later term you can calculate, and it is linear in $X$, as desired.

Comment: Not necessarly it has a density. I understand that we can also assume covariance matrix is not degenerate but do you know how to approach in general case?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mu_Y:=\mathsf{E}Y$, $\mu_X:=\mathsf{E}X$, $\Sigma_X:=\operatorname{Var}(X)$ $\Sigma_Y:=\operatorname{Var}(Y)$, and $\Sigma_{X,Y}=\mathsf{E}X(Y-\mu_Y)$. Consider the following transformation (assuming that $\Sigma_X$ is invertible):
$$
Z:=Y-\Sigma_{X,Y}^{\top}\Sigma_X^{-1}X.
$$
Since
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}X(Z-\mathsf{E}Z)^{\top}&=\mathsf{E}X(Y-\mu_Y-\Sigma_{X,Y}^{\top}\Sigma_X^{-1}(X-\mu_X))^{\top} \\
&=\Sigma_{X,Y}-\Sigma_X\Sigma_X^{-1}\Sigma_{X,Y}=0,
\end{align}
$Z$ and $X$ are independent (they're jointly Gaussian). Then
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]&=\mathsf{E}[Z\mid X]+\mathsf{E}[\Sigma_{X,Y}^{\top}\Sigma_X^{-1}X\mid X] \\
&=\mathsf{E}Z+\Sigma_{X,Y}^{\top}\Sigma_X^{-1}X=\mu_Y+\Sigma_{X,Y}^{\top}\Sigma_X^{-1}(X-\mu_X) \quad\text{a.s.}
\end{align}

---

When $\Sigma_X$ is singular, some coordinates of $X$ are affine functions of a subset $X^{*}$ of dimension $\operatorname{rank}(\Sigma_X)$ (assuming that $\operatorname{rank}(\Sigma_X)\ge 1$). In that case $\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X]=\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X^*]$, and $\operatorname{Var}(X^*)$ is invertible.

Comment: It is assuming that $X$ is non-degenerate? (Covariance matrix of $X$ is invertible?)